# How to make WebStorm Terminal functional in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webstorm

Can't use terminal in WebStorm, how can I resolve it? Notice how enter aren't processed, and text doesn't show up.

[image]

I've seen a lot of resolutions to similar issue for Windows 10, something about using Legacy Console.

It's not clear if that's possible in Windows 7.

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.5

Comment: For reference purposes: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000685670/comments/115000565824

Comment: @LazyOne haha thanks, I started that one. They led me here instead
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180993

Comment: I figure that out -- tat's why it's "for reference purposes". It will be useful for other people in similar situation (since it's better to have some link to a possible solution than hope to find it elsewhere or ask another question here).